# After "carton install" some dependencies have "0" as version

Tags: perl

New to Perl here, apologies for the maybe silly question. After running "carton install" I noticed in the cpanfile.snapshot that some dependencies still has "0" as version, so basically, no version was selected.

Is this the expected behaviour?

To be more precise, the dependency is declared in the cpanfile with "0" as version and does not appear in the snapshot file at all.

Comment: Were there any errors messages?

Comment: No errors, I am actually trying it with an open-source project:
https://github.com/skaji/perl-tldr
I am using carton version 1.0.28

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) :

> **PREREQ_PM**
> A hash of modules that are needed to run your module. The
> keys are the module names ie. `Test::More`, and the minimum version is
> the value. If the required version number is 0 any version will do.
> The versions given may be a Perl v-string (see version) or a range
> (see `CPAN::Meta::Requirements`).
>
> This will go into the requires field of your `META.yml` and the runtime
> of the prereqs field of your `META.json`.
>
> ```
> PREREQ_PM => {  
>     # Require Test::More at least 0.47
>     "Test::More" => "0.47",
>
>     # Require any version of Acme::Buffy
>     "Acme::Buffy" => 0, }
> ```

So a zero version in the `cpanfile.snapshot` means that a dependent or required module specified a version number of zero, meaning that any version will do.

> To be more precise, the dependency is declared in the cpanfile with "0" as version and does not appear in the snapshot file at all.

It depends if it is a core module or not, core modules are not included in the snapshot, but you can implicitly declare a version by specifying a minimum version for `perl` itself in the `cpanfile`:

```
requires 'perl', '5.022000';
```

See also [Specifying dependencies for your CPAN distribution](http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2017/05/specifying-dependencies-for-your-cpan-distribution.html) for more information.